# string in an Enum

Tags: c#

Given an enum like:

```
 enum Test
 {
   Hi=0x1,
   Hello=0x2
 }
```

From the database, I get either a 1 or 2.

I need to concatenate 0x (to display as hex value), when the query returns 1.

I concatenate 0x and when I assign, I get an invalid argument exception.

```
(Test)Enum.Parse(typeof(Test), reader.GetString(0));
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What's the value of reader.GetString(0)?  If it's not "Hi" or "Hello", this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

> Take a a string representation of a decimal number, and display that
>   number in hexidecimal form.

If so, try this:

```
String x = String.Format("{0:X2}", Int.Parse(myInteger));
```

Or perhaps I've misunderstood what your problem is.

Comment: In the database there is 1 or 2 (integers), the enum has Hi,Hello, for ex: Hi=0x1, Hello=0x2, so when i get 1 or 2 from DB i need to assign to an enum, in other words in DB decimal values are stored, i need to display hexa values from enum in the front end.

Comment: It should be inside an enum, i can't directly assign.

Comment: Looks this the closest approach for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
Test = (Test)int.Parse(reader.GetString(0));
```

That's bare minimum code, you need to do error checking and all that good stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but when i try this, i get System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's always [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx). If you're not on .NET 4.0 yet, implementing a similar method for your own use only requires a few steps:

```
static bool TryParseEnum<TEnum>(string text, out TEnum value)
{
    value = default(T);

    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(text, out number) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), number))
    {
        // This awkward double-cast is unfortunately necessary
        // due to the lack of a where T : enum constraint -- 
        // the compiler cannot guarantee that T is castable from int.
        value = (TEnum)(object)number;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, based on the answer you've accepted, it seems I may have misinterpreted your question! Nevertheless, I am leaving this answer here in case it's useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking to do, but if you want to convert a string value in a database that is "0x0" or "0x1", then you can use something like the code below for t1 & t3:

```
Test t1 = (Test) Enum.Parse(typeof (Test), Convert.ToInt32("0x0", 16).ToString());
Test t2 = (Test) Enum.Parse(typeof(Test), "0");
Test t3 = (Test) Enum.Parse(typeof(Test), Convert.ToInt32("0x1", 16).ToString());
Test t4 = (Test) Enum.Parse(typeof(Test), "1");
```